# QC OTA : How to add an Test Iteration in Test Lab->Test Set->Test case->Test Instance Details->Execution Settings using QC OTA

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

I am able to read the Test set and the tests in the set using OTA, but not able to get the object of Test Iteration in Test Lab.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIaue.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Test Iteration in Test Lab->Test Set->Test Case->Test Instance Details->Execution Settings using QC OTA.

First, you need to find the Test Case object. It's TSTest object, which represents a test instance, or execution test, in a test set.

Then, you need to modify the value of TC_DATA_OBJ of this test instance.

For example,

```
  ITestSetTreeManager testSetTreeManager = (ITestSetTreeManager)tdConnection.TestSetTreeManager;
  TestSetFolder Root = (TestSetFolder)testSetTreeManager.Root;
  TestSetFolder labFolder;
  try
  {
    labFolder = (TestSetFolder)Root.FindChildNode("TestSetFolder");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    labFolder = null;
  }
  if (labFolder != null)
  {
    TestSetFactory testSetFactory = (TestSetFactory)labFolder.TestSetFactory;
    List testSetList = testSetFactory.NewList("");
    if (testSetList.Count > 0)
    {
      for (int testSetIndex = 1; testSetIndex <= testSetList.Count; testSetIndex++)
      {
        TestSet testSet = testSetList[testSetIndex];
        TSTestFactory tsTestFactory = (TSTestFactory)testSet.TSTestFactory;
        List tsTestList = tsTestFactory.NewList("");
        TSTest tsTest;
        for (int tsTestIndex = 1; tsTestIndex <= tsTestList.Count; tsTestIndex++)
        {
          tsTest = tsTestList[tsTestIndex];
          if (tsTest.Type == "BUSINESS-PROCESS")
          {
            string xml =
              "<DATAPACKET data_type=\"manual\"><CONFIGURATION><SELECTION first_sel_row=\"-1\" last_sel_row=\"-1\" /></CONFIGURATION><METADATA><COLUMNS>" +
              "<COLUMN column_name=\"p1\" column_value_type=\"String\" />" +
              "<COLUMN column_name=\"p2\" column_value_type=\"String\" />" +
              "<COLUMN column_name=\"p3\" column_value_type=\"String\" />" +
              "<COLUMN column_name=\"p4\" column_value_type=\"String\" /></COLUMNS></METADATA><ROWADATA>" +
              "<ROW col1=\"11\" col2=\"12\" col3=\"13\" col4=\"14\"/>" +
              "<ROW col1=\"21\" col2=\"22\" col3=\"23\" col4=\"24\"/>" +
              "<ROW col1=\"31\" col2=\"32\" col3=\"33\" col4=\"34\"/>" +
              "</ROWADATA></DATAPACKET>";
            tsTest["TC_DATA_OBJ"] = xml;
            tsTest.Post();         
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Note:

If you want to add a test iteration using QC OTA, you also need to keep the old values.

You just need to append a row in the below and input the value of each column. 
And others remain unchanged.

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Thank you and regards,

Wenjuan